# Longest *fairy* chess problem

Tags: problems, chess-variants, records

[Longest orthodox chess problem](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/31684/what-is-the-longest-checkmate-problem-a-human-has-composed/31690#31690)

One for the specialists. In the newest SCHWALBE I saw some titanic lengths (one problem had 2^59+2^57+3 ~ 10^18 moves!) As you see, this scales with O(2^(n^2)), where n is the chess board length. Which is rather puny to what *might* be possible, e.g. a problem scaling with the [Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function). Anyone knowing the current record holder for any fairy chess problem, no holds barred, only uniqueness of solution is required?

EDIT (due to comments): You can have an arbitrarily-sized board or sneak in infinity via new pieces. In this sense, the answer *is* "infinity". So I should better ask for an actual, printed, stipulation of the form "Something happens in n moves", where you "just" have to beat the above value. In the Dawson example, the possible infinity is stated (and the first n values on largers board are given in a reprint - I know this problem from there), but these printed n are of course <<10^18.

Comment: Almost certainly the record holder is the problem that you sketched vaguely in the question. Please post details of that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Is there a clear definition of what constitutes a "fairy" problem?  For instance, if you can stipulate a change to the dimensions of the board, then solutions of an infinite length could be devised.  Here's an amusing example of such a "dimensional" puzzle:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, in this sense there is no maximum.

Comment: Why is the expanded board trimmed and not a square?

Comment: @Laska: Bh1 will run to the hills :-)

Answer (score 1):

On request, here is the problem: SCHWALBE 324-2, Article "Die Valladao-Challenge" by Jochen Schröder, p.389, Nr. 5, by Jochen Schröder, help-aim square h8, 2+59, in 720575940379279357 moves, conditions Antigrid, king dynasty, shortestmover w, diagram anticirce Cheylan w, sentinelles generalises en, noires wb, and black pawns everywhere *except* ws a5, wk b3, empty a1 h1, bb b1 c1 f1 g1, bk d1, drop hole e1. Solution implements a waiting queue and I won't type it here, see article.